# Is a JOIN clause essential in finding a difference of tables in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I am trying to find the difference of ID from 2 tables. I have posted the sample data of Table 1 and Table 2. I was thinking of using OUTER JOIN, but realized that may not be the best idea. What is a simple way to find the desired goal using JOIN? Would any JOIN clause help in this case? If not, what is the best (yet simple) approach to this? I appreciate everyone's help with this!

Table 1:

| Person | Package ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y788 | 01-01-2020 |
| 2 | T932 | 01-02-2020 |
| 3 | W345 | 01-03-2020 |
| 3 | S122 | 01-03-2020 |
| 4 | F567 | 01-04-2020 |
| 4 | H767 | 01-04-2020 |

Table 2:

| Person | Package ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y788 | 01-01-2020 |
| 2 | T932 | 01-02-2020 |
| 3 | W345, S122 | 01-03-2020 |
| 4 | F567, H767 | 01-04-2020 |
| 5 | C555 | 01-05-2020 |

Desired Goal (after coding):

| Person | Package ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | C555 | 01-05-2020 |

Code:

```
SELECT Person, Package ID, Date
from table1, table2 
OUTER JOIN Person.table1 = Person.table2
Group by Date 
Order by Person;
```

Comment: no essential it is not there are other constrict like IN but you really should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Since you seem to want rows which doesn't exist in the other table, a `LEFT JOIN` would make most sense. You've got another issue though; you want to compare the separate values of person 4 with the concatenated values in another table. This is another good example why you shouldn't combine values in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment i already mentioned that saving data  in delimited column is a bad idea, as it complicates matters and makes the query slow see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

The rest is basic sql

A LEFT JOIN is needed to get all rows in table2 that are not in table1.

The where clause only works, because there are no spaces between the data in table2, so if you have them you need to replace them.

```
SELECT table2."Person", table2."Package ID", table2."Date"  
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON  table1."Person" = table2."Person"
WHERE  (',' || table2."Package ID" || ',') NOT LIKE ('%,' || COALESCE(table1."Package ID",'') || ',%')
```

```
| Person | Package ID | Date |
| :-------|:-----------|:-----|
| 5 | C555 | 01-05-2020 |
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/poqll6O8)